# Should I use datatable to store one column of select query in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

My sql select query will return one column of company names (many rows of names). Now I want to store it. I used:

```
 try
 {
      connection.Open();
      sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection);
      SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      dt.Clear();

      sqlReader.Read();
      dt.Load(sqlReader);
```

Then I tried to access the name by

```
dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()
dt.Rows[1][0].ToString()
dt.Rows[2][0].ToString()
etc.
```

But I recognize that the value in dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() is different from time to time, event if I use the same query, and it looks like that the old values still stored in the datatable event if I use new query value.
How is the right way to store and retrieve values here?

Comment: I think there is something elsewhere in the code that needs attention.

Comment: If you are not sorting the resultset in the query based on a non-null, unique key, it is possible for the query to return different result each time. Also, you might want to call the dispose on the DataTable object after usage and then use it again for the next query call.

Comment: Ok, I tried with select distinct so it will sort and no duplicate. I just tried dispose(). But now no result so.

Comment: I mean the old result is still there. It is not clear form datatable

Comment: From the code above, you declare a local variable called dt, there is no need to Clear it just after the creation. The Load callcannot append to anything already there because there is nothing to append to. So your problem is elsewhere. How do you use that variable? What is the CommandText used? Why do you call Read before the DataTable.Load?

Comment: I need to call read so that the result from the sql query will be in sqlReader. Then only after that I load the result into dt. The commandText use sql select command.

Comment: Do you have an order by clause in your select query? If not, add it and your query will always return results in the same order.

Comment: I have select by distinct and I see it order by alphabet. I will add order by as you suggested but I cannot connect to server to test now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use,

```
string compnay_name = dt.Rows[0]["column_name"].ToString();
```

### Try using your compnay name column in double quote.

You can use it in a for or foreach loop.
as,

```
for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
   string compnay_name = dt.Rows[i]["column_name"].ToString();
}
```

Hope it helps...
Aki

Comment: How to make sure the datatable is clean and refresh after each time I query new value?

Comment: Use DataTable.Clear Method.

also,
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)

Here, dt stands for datatable object.

Comment: I used that one! DataTable dt = new DataTable();dt.clear(); But the result is the same!

Comment: Yes. It is ok now. I am not sure because of dt.clear() or by ordering in sql statement. However I will choose your answer as it is the only one and also contribute to my result ! Thank you !